# Need to upload file via gcloud to server from localmachine - INSUFFICIENT PERMISSIONS?

Tags: upload, server, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have tried looking for an answer to this problem for over a month. Apparently I am the only one in the world who ever had this issue... Here's the console commands I am giving over ssh. I am logged into the only account with permissions and it has FULL permissions over the project... I am stumped.

```
sudo gcloud compute copy-files /home/lestado/trs.key adminuser@the-real-strategy-vm:/etc/ssl/private/
```

**This is the response I am getting:**

```
Did you mean zone [us-central1-f] for instances: 

[['[the-real-strategy-vm]']]?

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) Could not fetch instance:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your project name before you start copying files.

```
gcloud config set project <project_name>
```

Complete process will be:

- Login: `gcloud init`
- Set project: `gcloud config set project <project_name>`
- Upload using root user for instance: `gcloud compute copy-files ./ root@instance:/etc/ssl/pvt`

Comment: Note that `gcloud init` sets project for you already so no need to run `gcloud config set` afterwards.